# How to convert from matrix like data to panel Format

Tags: r, matrix, reshape, sapply

I am a very beginner in working with R. This question therefore can be considered as a basic one.

I am trying to convert data in matrix format to panel data format when A, B or C = 0 For example:

```
set.seed(0); mat <- matrix(sample(0:1, 16, replace=T), ncol=4, nrow=4)
colnames (mat) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
rownames (mat) <- c("1","2", "3", "4")
```

to a panel format like:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
A 4
B 1
B 2
B 3
B 4
```

for every letter where variable "1"-"4" are 0.

I tried using the apply codes from the plyr package. Can someone provide me the right code and argument for letting R know that it should extract A, B, C or D if "1"=0 and repeat the same process for "2", "3" and "4" and that R puts the output underneath the former in a new dataframe?

I realized the above stated question is not clear enough. I therefore make it more clear by the hand of the mtcars dataset.

```
cars <- mtcars
```

In case of this dataset, the format I would like is:

```
Mazda RX4     | mpg   | 21.0
Mazda RX4     | cyl   | 6
Mazda RX4     | disp  | 160.0
...
Mazda RX4 Wag | mpg   | 21.0
Mazda RX4 Wag | cyl   | 6
...
```

and so on.

Comment: Your expected result seems not to match the `mat` created by your code snippet. With `mat` I do get A2, A3, B2, C3, C4, D1, D3. Is this the intended result?

Answer (score 0):

**A note**: You keep refering to the rows as *variables*. Having your variables in a row is at the very least confusing if not straight out dangerous because people expect variables to be in a column!
If your variables are called `"1",...,"4"` then I assume `A,...,D` refers to your observations? This would be even more confusing...

If you are interessted in what makes data tidy you should read Hadley Wickhams's revealing [article on tidy data](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10).

### EDIT:

**Regarding your question**:

Using the `mtcars` dataset and functions from the `tidyr` and `dplyr` package:

```
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
 add_rownames() %>% 
 gather("id", "value", mpg:carb) %>% 
 arrange(rowname)

Source: local data frame [352 x 3]

       rowname    id   value
         (chr) (chr)   (dbl)
1  AMC Javelin   mpg  15.200
2  AMC Javelin   cyl   8.000
3  AMC Javelin  disp 304.000
4  AMC Javelin    hp 150.000
5  AMC Javelin  drat   3.150
6  AMC Javelin    wt   3.435
7  AMC Javelin  qsec  17.300
8  AMC Javelin    vs   0.000
9  AMC Javelin    am   0.000
10 AMC Javelin  gear   3.000
..         ...   ...     ...
```

If you dont know the `%>%` operator (called *pipe-operator*) just read it as "and then".

Answer (score 0):

For the `mtcar`example this piece of code

```
library(data.table)
cars <- as.data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames = TRUE)
melt(cars, id.vars = "rn")[order(rn)]
```

will give

```
              rn variable  value
  1: AMC Javelin      mpg  15.20
  2: AMC Javelin      cyl   8.00
  3: AMC Javelin     disp 304.00
  4: AMC Javelin       hp 150.00
  5: AMC Javelin     drat   3.15
 ---                            
348:  Volvo 142E     qsec  18.60
349:  Volvo 142E       vs   1.00
350:  Volvo 142E       am   1.00
351:  Volvo 142E     gear   4.00
352:  Volvo 142E     carb   2.00
```

Note that `mtcars` is a `data.frame` not a `matrix`.

The solution for the matrix `mat` given in the Q is

```
melt(as.data.table(mat, keep.rownames = TRUE), id.vars = "rn")[value == 0][
  order(variable, rn), .(variable, rn)]
```

which will return

```
    rn variable value
1:        A  2
2:        A  3
3:        B  2
4:        C  3
5:        C  4
6:        D  1
7:        D  3
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment. Both this code and the one provided by Manuel S did their job well! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GerwinColjé Then, would you mind to upvote both answers, please. Thanks.

Comment: I did, however I must first earn 15 reputation points (I am new at the forum since this week), then the votes become public unfortunately. @UweBlock